# Retrieving bool array from NSUserdefaults in swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, nsuserdefaults

I have defined an array like this in my iOS app

```
var array=[Bool]()
```

and assigning some bool values to this.After that I am storing this array in my user defaults in this way.

```
userDefaults.setObject(dm.array, forKey: "array")
```

Now I want to retrievw this array. So I did like this

```
dm.array=userDefaults.arrayForKey("array") as! Array
```

But here im getting an error

> Down cast from '[AnyObject]?' to 'Array' only unwraps optional; did you mean to use '!'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
array = userDefaults.objectForKey("array") as? [Bool] ?? [Bool]()
```